# Customize wordpress media uploader button text

Tags: plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working on a simple little plugin and needed an image loader. I wanted to use the default Wordpress one so it could access the library, that was all pretty simple. All I need is the ability to select an image, nothing else is wanted.

I've managed to remove the unwanted inputs using the attachment_fields_to_edit filter, and the unwanted gallery tab with the media_upload_tabs filter, but what I can't seem to be able to remove is the other stuff on the page, Specifically I'm talking about the "Use as featured image" link and the "Save all changes" button. I'd also really like to change the button text from "Insert into Post" to something more appropriate to what the plugin is actually doing.

I've googled and dug through the WP files but didn't see anything that would let me actually change that (while I'd prefer something gracefull I'd take a simple html filter before it sends the uploader output to the browser and use regular expressions to get the job done at this rate). Best I've been able to do is remove the "Inser into Post" line of options, which isn't very helpful as then there is no wat to actually select the image.

Has anybody done this before? I'm surprised theres not a simple hook that lets you change those (or that I couldn't find a hook if there is one).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/how-to-hook-into-the-media-upload-popup-interface and section "4. Set Our Own Action". That seems to be exactly what you're after.